# Element of exhaustion being connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, pick any $y \in U$ I can construct an *exhaustion* of $U$ as the following:
$$U_k = \left \{ x \in U \mid d(x,y) \leq k, d(x,\partial U) \geq d(y,\partial U)/(k+1) \right \}$$
It is obvioust that $(U_k)$ forms an open cover of $U$ and each $\overline{U_k}$ is relatively compact in $U$. My question is how to prove $U_k$ is connected for $k$ large enough?

When I encounter this problem I though $U_k$ is either convex or at least I can join pairs of points in $U_k$ by piecewise-paths but nothing of them work and no idea appears in my mind anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a $U$ consisting of an infinite "string of beads". The beads are open balls connected to their neighbors by necks that get thinner and thinner as you go down the string. For any fixed $y$ and $k$, eventually you will get to a neck so thin that the points in it are not in $U_k$, but the bead beyond still will be. Ergo, every $U_k$ is disconnected, even though $U$ is not.